# .NET 7 Middleware return image not working on multiple images

Tags: .net, middleware

I have some images in a specific folder need to be protected. for this I created a middleware to handle it. I added the code below. it is .NET 7 MVC in C#.

My code kind of working, so basically, if the user has permission I returned the image. I tested it from the browser by use the correct url. it works for single image request.

The issue I have is, when I request multiple images (user has permissions to all) from the same page, the images returned are most likely the last image, and even the Trace.WriteLine can not log the correct requested image file name, it randomly log the request, but mostly is the last one, for my example will be img_3.jpg.

Please help me, what is the problem and how to solve it. Thanks a lot!

the request causing issue like:

```
<img src="~/assets/album/image/img_1.jpg" class="img-fluid"  />
<img src="~/assets/album/image/img_2.jpg" class="img-fluid"  />
<img src="~/assets/album/image/img_3.jpg" class="img-fluid"  />
```

```
// use the middleware in the program.cs file
app.Map("/assets/album/image", MyMiddleware.HandleAlbumImages);  //before use static files
app.UseStaticFiles();


// define the classes for my middleware

public static class MyMiddleware
{
    public static void HandleAlbumImages(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var options = Options.Create(new AlbumMiddlewareOptions(".jpg"));
        app.UseMiddleware<AlbumMiddleware>(options);
    }
}

public class AlbumMiddlewareOptions {
    public string Ext { get; set; } = "";   // .jpg or .zip
    public AlbumMiddlewareOptions(string ext) { 
        Ext = ext;
    }
}

public class AlbumMiddleware {
    protected TConfig _config = null;
    protected string _webRootPath = "";
    protected MyRepository _db = null;
    public string RequstPathFull { get; set; } = "";
    public string Ext { get; set; } = "";   // .jpg or .zip
    public AlbumMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<AlbumMiddlewareOptions> option, IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, MyRepository repository)
    {
        _config = configuration.GetSection("SiteSettings").Get<TConfig>();
        _webRootPath = webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        _db = repository;
        Ext = option.Value.Ext;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {       
        if (await ValidateRequest(context, Ext))
        {            
            await context.Response.SendFileAsync(RequstPathFull);
        }
        else
        {
            string invalid = "invalid";
            await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(invalid);
        }
    }

    // basically here I check my database to see if the user has permission, some code is ignored
    protected async Task<bool> ValidateRequest(HttpContext context, string ext)
    {
        string requestFile = context.Request.Path.ToString() ?? "";
        RequstPathFull = $"{_webRootPath}{context.Request.PathBase}{context.Request.Path}".Replace("/", "\\");
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"MW: {RequstPathFull}");
        var itemId = 10;    // it is extracted from the file name
        var memberId = 1;   // this is from the session
        if (await _db.IfMemberOwnAlbumImage(memberId, itemId))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you're using `~` in your URIs - are you certain that's getting converted into the correct **rendered** URI? ...if you arne't using ASP.NET Core MVC with TagHelpers then that might not be converted...

Comment: the ~ is not the issue, I tried with and without it, even the full URL start with https

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [conventional-based middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-7.0) - your middleware is constructed once per application lifetime. That is why the last request overrides the `RequestPathFull`. Probably, your middleware would work, but as a [factory-based middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/extensibility?view=aspnetcore-7.0), which is created per request.

Comment: I tried this by adding the IMiddleWare, and wire it up. it seems captured my get and JavaScript Post, but not the request to static images within the page, it works if I try browse the image by URL.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the "Map" to "UseWhen", and the invoke call not to return the file and go next, so if has permission, let the static file middleware handle it later on. it is working from my tests. But I still want to figure out why the "map" and SendFileAsync not working.

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/assets/album/image"), MyMiddleware.HandleAlbumImages);
```

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{       
    if (await ValidateRequest(context, Ext))
    {            
        //await context.Response.SendFileAsync(RequstPathFull);
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
    else
    {
        string invalid = "invalid";
        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(invalid);
    }
}
```